# iPhone headache - Threads, notifications, and URL Async connections

Tags: iphone, multithreading, asynchronous, notifications, nsurlrequest

Some code instead of a long explanation.
The problem is :

When called from `viewDidLoad`, the server call triggers the delegates methods (connectionDidFinishLoading, etc...). But when called from `XMLFileFullParsed`, the request is launched to the server, but those same methods are not triggered.

If i call `[self loadXMLDatas]` instead of threading it, both server calls work fine.

Why ?

I start here :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(foundaTag:) name:@"foundaTag" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(XMLFileFullParsed:) name:@"XMLFileFullParsed" object:nil];

    self.server = [[ServerCommManager alloc] initWithServer:@"http://someserver/"];
    [self.server sendQuestionWithCallIdentifier:@"IDENTIFIER" onPage:@"testpage.php" withParams:nil sendAnswerToObject:self];  // -- This one works 

    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadXMLDatas) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

- (void) loadXMLDatas {
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; 
Do things, create a XMLparser, start to parse.
[pool release];
}

- (void) XMLFileFullParsed:(NSNotification*)notification {

    [self.server sendQuestionWithCallIdentifier:@"IDENTIFIER" onPage:@"testpage.php" withParams:nil sendAnswerToObject:self]; // -- This one doesn't work
}
```

## XMLParser.m

```
- (void) doYourJob {
    [self doTheJob];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"XMLFileFullParsed" object:nil userInfo:nil];
}

- (void) doTheJob:(XMLTag*)tag {
    if ([tag.name isEqualToString:@"searchedtag"]) {
       theData = extract some datas
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"foundaTag" object:self userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:theData forKey:@"data"]];
        return;
    }

    for (XMLTag* aTag in tag.childtags) {
        [self doTheJob:aTag];
    }
}
```

## Deep inside the server comm.m

```
- (void) executeRequest  {
   some init
self.connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse*)response  {

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data  
{

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didFailWithError:(NSError*)error 
{

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection 
{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you've given, the notification is being posted from another Thread rather than the Main Thread where you've registered the observer.

In [Apple's Notification Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html), it says

> In a multithreaded application, notifications are always delivered in the thread in which the notification was posted, which may not be the same thread in which an observer registered itself.

What you can do is move the notification into it's own method and then use performSelectorOnMainThread like so:

```
- (void) doTheJob:(XMLTag*)tag {
    if ([tag.name isEqualToString:@"searchedtag"]) {
       theData = extract some datas
       [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(sendNotification:) withObject:theData waitUntilDone:YES];
        return;
    }

    for (XMLTag* aTag in tag.childtags) {
        [self doTheJob:aTag];
    }
}

- (void)sendNotification:(NSArray *)theData {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"foundaTag" object:self userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:theData forKey:@"data"]];
}
```

Comment: The problem is not the notification, that is received. The problem is the URLConnection response that is not triggered.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I misread the question. Are you sure self.server is still pointing to something rather than nil? Putting a quick NSLog(@"%@", self.server); in - (void) XMLFileFullParsed:(NSNotification*)notification will give you the result

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, as the request is launched. But I found the problem following your answer. The problem is that the request is launched on a thread that is killed when the answer arrives. I changed my code so I launch the request from the main thread, and that works fine.